# On time-dependent invariant Riemannian metrics

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $X$ be a $G$-homogeneous space that admits a $C^\infty$ family of invariant Riemannian metrics $(\alpha,\beta)\ni t\mapsto g(t)$. Then there exists a family $(\alpha,\beta)\ni t\mapsto\Phi(t)\in\mathrm{Diff}(X)$ of diffeomorphisms of $X$ such that the map $(t,x)\mapsto \Phi(t)x$ is $C^\infty((\alpha,\beta)\times X,X)$ and $d\Phi(t)^*g(t)=g(0)$ for all $t\in(\alpha,\beta)$.

This can be proven by first constructing the map locally through the exponential map, then using the $G$-equivariance of the exponential map to glue local maps etc. But I am pretty sure that this can be found somewhere in the literature.

**Question:** Would you, please, provide a reference where a proof of this statement can be found or at least easily read off from a stronger statement.

Thank you.